# how to fetch data from a api that has HTTP in github

Tags: javascript, api, web

So I was trying to host my project of weather app in Github that fetches it's data from Accu weather API which I think uses a http and I am unable to fetch data and getting a error.

Error message:

> forecast.js:21 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://alapottra-troj1n.github.io/Weather-App/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/search?apikey=xxx&q=Rangamati'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
> .

Is there any way in Github that allows me to get data from a http website.. or are there any alternative free hosting website like Github that I can use

Comment: Just add an `s` to the http: `https://dataservice.accuweather.com`

Comment: Feel free to delete the question. It is exposing your API key and is answered by adding an s to your protocol

Answer (score 0):

just request the api with https, it is working!

https://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/search?key=dsadasq=Rangamati

generally mixed content error is from the browser, it has nothing to do with github, it would affect any site where there is mixed content, you could edit you browser settings, but they are only for you https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/target/using/experiences/vec/troubleshoot-composer/mixed-content.html?lang=en#task_5448763B8DC941FD80F84041AEF0A14D

Comment: You have enough rep to vote to close as typotype

Comment: Thankyou for the fast response.. It works

Comment: sry, i didnt see that, i removed it

Comment: But why answer at all. It is a "typo-type" question and already answered in the fist comment to the question